# How to solve compilation error "undefined" in sass-compiler for Visual Studio?

Tags: css, web, sass, compiler-errors

I am getting this error when compiling valid SASS in my App.scss file.

[image]

If I delete the import statement, the error fires on the next import statement.
If I rename the file (there is only one file to be imported - I checked in Windows Explorer), the erorr fires regardless of the name.

I also tried

```
@import './mixins/breakpoints2';
```

I am using the Visual Studio Code plugin named "Live Sass Compiler" version 3.0.0.

The full error message is "Compilation Error
Error: It's not clear which file to import for '@import "d:\Programmeren\reminderapp-reactjs\src\mixins_breakpoints2.scss"'."

Comment: Missing some vital information to help you out. What's the full error message? How're you compiling your sass, a Code plugin, gulp, grunt, webpack ?

Comment: I am compiling my sass using the plugin "Live Sass compiler" of Visual Studio Code

Comment: Did you define your mixin twice?

Comment: @anderssonola The full error message: " Error: It's not clear which file to import for '@import "d:\Programmeren\reminderapp-reactjs\src\mixins\_breakpoints2.scss"' "

Comment: @QuentinVeron No, I only defined it once.